# How to escape slash in gcloud format / filter command?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I would like to filter Cloud Run revisions by its container image.

When I run this gcloud run revisions command,

```
gcloud beta run revisions list --service sample-service --region=asia-northeast1 --limit=5 --sort-by="~DEPLOYED" --format="json"
```

it will output following json

```json
[
  {
    "apiVersion": "serving.knative.dev/v1",
    "kind": "Revision",
    "metadata": {
      "annotations": {
        "autoscaling.knative.dev/maxScale": "1",
        "client.knative.dev/user-image": "asia.gcr.io/sample-gcp-project/sample-app:e88597bcfb346aa1",
        "run.googleapis.com/client-name": "gcloud",
        "run.googleapis.com/client-version": "383.0.1", #
```

I tried to filter revisions by --filter options, but it raises an error.

```sh
gcloud beta run revisions list --service it-sys-watch --region=asia-northeast1 --limit=1 --sort-by="~DEPLOYED" --filter='metadata.annotations.client.knative.dev/user-image=asia.gcr.io/sample-gcp-project/sample-app:e88597bcfb346aa1'
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.revisions.list) Non-empty key name expected [metadata.annotations.client.knative.dev *HERE* /user-image=asia.gcr.io/sample-gcp-project/sample-app:e88597bcfb346aa1].
```

Neither adding backslash nor double slashes won't work

```
gcloud beta run revisions list --service it-sys-watch --region=asia-northeast1 --limit=1 --sort-by="~DEPLOYED" --filter='metadata.annotations.client.knative.dev\/user-image=asia.gcr.io/sample-gcp-project/sample-app:e88597bcfb346aa1'
WARNING: The following filter keys were not present in any resource : metadata.annotations.client.knative.dev\/user-image
Listed 0 items.

gcloud beta run revisions list --service it-sys-watch --region=asia-northeast1 --limit=1 --sort-by="~DEPLOYED" --filter='metadata.annotations.client.knative.dev//user-image=asia.gcr.io/sample-gcp-project/sample-app:e88597bcfb346aa1'
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.revisions.list) Non-empty key name expected [metadata.annotations.client.knative.dev *HERE* //user-image=asia.gcr.io/sample-gcp-project/sample-app:e88597bcfb346aa1].
```

`gcloud --format` options also does not work with backslash keys.

Is there any idea to help filtering key with slashes?

Comment: I don't have a service deployed to test this but can you try `--filter='metadata.annotations["client.knative.dev/user-image"]="asia.gcr.io/sample-gcp-project/sample-app:e88597bcfb346aa1"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```sh
gcloud beta run revisions list \
--service=it-sys-watch \
--region=asia-northeast1 \
--sort-by="~DEPLOYED" \
--filter='metadata.annotations["client.knative.dev/user-image"]="asia.gcr.io/sample-gcp-project/sample-app:e88597bcfb346aa1"'
```

> **NOTE** You need to drop the `--limit=1` too though this conflicts with the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/revisions/list#--limit) that suggests that `limit` is applied after `filter`
>
> `gcloud ... --filter=... --limit=1 | jq 'length'` yields `0`
>
> `gcloud ... --filter=... | jq 'length'` yields 1
>
> Let's see what Google Engineering says: [231192444](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/231192444)